# How to understand type hierarchy feature in Eclipse for java project

Tags: java, eclipse

For learning purposes, I am trying to import a java project, Lingpipe, into Eclipse. I used the “open Type Hierarchy” feature offered in Eclipse. The following figure is a screenshot. I do not quite understand what does those label mean, such as C with superscript S, or C with superscript A, or C with superscript F. In addition, some of them are marked with red. I use yellow color and red arrow line to mark some labels that I am referring to.  In addition, how does this kind of type hierarchy help us to understand a java project?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by SimonC is correct but I guess you still need clarification on how it helps the user.

To be specific,
**C means Class
F means Final Class
S mean Static Class
A means Abstract**

all these notations helps user to indicate the class they are seeing is what kind of class.
And
**Red dot is for Private Fields or Class or Method. Depending upon what object is referred. Same with Blue Triangle you see is for the package visibility.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse icons are documented here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm

To answer your specific question, the C icon is a class, the supercsript A is abtract, S static, F final.  The red square means it's private, the blue triangle is package scoped.

Amongst other things, the type hierarchy helps to understand what behaviour a class inherits from it's parent types.

Comment: thanks for the response. If it is possible, could you explain which kind of behavior I can get just based on this screenshot?